# How can I logout my app using REDIS + Node.js

Tags: node.js, express, redis, mean-stack, logout

I am implementing logout function. I am using this technologies first time so can any please help me.
Using: 
**angularJS 
Node.js 
Redis**

**AngularJS code**

```
<md-button md-no-ink class="md-primary" ng-click="logoutCall()">logout</md-button>
```

**Controller.js**

```
$scope.logoutCall = function(){
      var req = $http.get("api/logout");
      console.log(" in side logout call function!");
      // some fun stuff ....

}
```

**Redis code**

```
router.route("/logout")
    .get(
        function(req, res){
            verifyAuth(req, res, function(err, authorized){
                if(err){
                    res.json(err);
                    return;
                };
            // ---- fun stuff conti. -----
            console.log("regis api/logout");
            });
    });
```

**function verifyAuth()**

```
//verify authorization
var verifyAuth = function(req, res, callBack){

    if(req.headers && req.headers.hasOwnProperty("x-auth-token")){
        // get the redis client and try to get the corresponding object using the auth_token as a key
        var redisClient = redis.getClient();
        redisClient.get('auth_token.' + req.headers["x-auth-token"], function(err, reply){
            if(err || !reply){
                callBack({error:"Unauthorized: Please sign in"});
                return;
            }

            // refresh the session expire to 20 mins
            redisClient.expire('auth_token.' + req.headers["x-auth-token"], 1200); 
            req.user = JSON.parse(reply);
            callBack(null, true);

        });
    }else{
       callBack({error:"Missing Authentication: Please sign in"});
       return;
    }
};
```

Comment: well, you can generate a token an store it in redis under a unique-key (userid) and on logout, you can delete the key from the redis.

Comment: thanks @Nivesh for quick reply but can you share some code.. ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

// logout route
**Redis code**

```
 router.route("/logout")
        .get(
            function(req, res){
                var redisClient = redis.getClient();
                redisClient.del('auth_token.' + req.headers["x-auth-token"], function(err, reply){
                    if(!err || reply){
                        console.log("del token ");
                        res.sendStatus(401);
                        return;
                }


            });
        });
```

Use Http interceptor to catch this error code.
**HttpInterceptor:**

```
function responseError( response ) {

    console.log("inside responseError" + response.status);
        switch ( response.status ) {
            //...can handle different error codes differently

            case 401:
                $rootScope.$broadcast( 'httpError', { message: 'logout successful' } );

                $state.go('login page'); 
                break;
        }

        return $q.reject( response );
    }
```